# text-rotation - problem with IE

Tags: css, text-rotation

Hi I'm trying to rotate a text, but i'm facing some problems with IE 8 and 9

```
.casaText{
     display:block;     
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-filter:rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
```

In IE it doens't rotate. Does anyone can tell me why??

thanks

Comment: is it something wrong with answers?

Comment: The question already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's this property causing the problem:

```
-ms-filter:rotate(-90deg);
```

I'm not aware of any proprietary IE filter like that.  Try this:

```
.casaText{
     display:block;     
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)";
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: That's wired. I did a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/PrXsR) and it's fine on IE, but in my web site it isn't working on IE. any ideas??

Comment: @user794035 Is IE blocking ActiveX controls or scripting on your website?

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your code

> `-ms-filter:rotate(-90deg);`

For crossbrowser rotation use this syntax from [css3please.com](http://css3please.com/), which in your case look like this:

```
.casaText{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
       -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* IE9 */
         -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
               filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=6.123031769111886e-17, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=6.123031769111886e-17, sizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE 6-9 */
                 zoom: 1; /* IE hasLayout trigger */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Matrix for the rotation:

Here is for `-90deg`

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=6.123233995736766e-17, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=6.123233995736766e-17, sizingMethod='auto expand');
zoom: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked well.  I found it from css-tricks.com (which is a great resource gotta say).  Anyway, worked for me.  I realize this is a bit late - ha - but maybe it will help someone else who find this like I did.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=$m11, M12=$m12, M21=$m21, M22=$m22, sizingMethod='auto expand');
```