# text rotation 270 degree in IE8

Tags: html, css

I have found various methods for text rotations compatible with IE8. It is working for all other degrees, but not 270.

Method 1:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)";
```

----NOT WORKING---

Method 2:

```
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=6.123233995736766e-17, M12=1,           M21=-1, M22=6.123233995736766e-17, sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

----NOT WORKING---

Method 3:
Using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <title>Sideway</title>
    <style>
#image{
  margin:200px 300px;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="image">
    Hi how are you
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
    <script>
$("#image").rotate(270);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---NOT WORKING EITHER------

PS: The problem regarding is only with IE8 and especially 270 degrees rotation.

Comment: I say this without any experience or knowledge of jquery, but can you use `-90`?

Comment: yes tried with -90 too.. but no fruit..

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900870/rotating-a-text-to-270-degrees-in-ie8)

Comment: yes mark thanks for finding.. But Ive tried those suggested methods.. but not rotating 270 in IE8...  Here is also another thread relevant I found out now.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232761/text-rotation-problem-with-ie