# Rotate not being applied to inner elements in i.e

Tags: css, rotation

I have created a div and in that div there are three other elements(canvas). I have applied rotation to that div and it perfectly applies to inner elements too in firefox and chrome. But in I.E the rotation is not being applied on inner elements. Is there some special way for i.e?

Here is code for rotaion,

```
transform: rotate(-5deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Firefox */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.992546151641322, M12=0.12186934340514761, M21=-0.12186934340514761, M22=0.992546151641322, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

Comment: Same problem here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Comment: That's not the same question!!!

Comment: Yes, it is. IE doesn't know about rotate, so you have to use filters. This, or you weren't explicit enoght about what you want. This is what I understood from your question

Comment: Just read it again. I said that rotation is not being applied on INNER elements of div.

Comment: I have already applied the filter same as in the question you reffered!