# Text rotation on Internet explorer

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS rotate property in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)

Can any one help here to rotate the text on IE- 8, IE -7 versions. 
it is working on Chome, firefox, IE-9, but doesn`t have any results on IE-8, IE- 7.

```
<a href="#" class="beta_home">BETA</a>

css
a.beta_home{
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 12px;
  right:0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color:red;
  border: 1px solid #fff; 
  display: block; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

i wouldn't pref to do it in any browser cause they all render it very different.. but you could do it with javascript

**Documentation**
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

**Commands**
$('#theimage').rotateRight(45);
$('#theimage').rotateLeft();

This would render it the same in IE 9, chrome, firefox, opera and safari cause its using a canvas object instead of turning the text by browser rendering

It will use the old codings for ie8, 7 & 6 Generate it [here](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/)

```
/* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=-0.1763269807084645, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
/* IE6 and 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix( M11=1, M12=-0.1763269807084645, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

**Working ex**

IE 7&8 tested
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8848/6/) (margins need to be different in chrome and other browsers cant say why but it does)

If you dont know how to differ css trough out the different browsers see this [link](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

**My opinion**

Beside all this i would recommend you make it as a picture (already rotated) using photoshop or if your dont have access to such programs use free ([GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/))

Comment: how about older IE browsers?

Comment: i will use the -ms-filter and filter: progid

Comment: just read from the library page, it supports IE7 & IE8. Not tested yet.

Comment: Quote from site "The library has been tested with: Mozilla FireFox 2.0.0.2, Internet Explorer 7.0, Opera 9.1 (note Opera 8 is not supported)"

Comment: Yes Even i've tried with jquery but the older browser of IE doesnot supporting the text rotation.

Comment: Can you please give me any demo link so that i can test the same on the IE older version and can use the same.

Comment: I have given you a working test without the JS cause i dont have a git where i can link to :)

Comment: @KiranSKK remember to inspect your testing (use chrome or firebug) for css debugging, the rotate causes alot of displacement so use margins to replace it or (position: absolute;)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=-0.1763269807084645, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
/* IE6 and 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix( M11=1, M12=-0.1763269807084645, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');

/* For IE6 and 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this online service:

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

It transform css3 rule

```
rotate(-90deg)
```

applied on `div` with `WIDTH: 220px; HEIGHT: 70px;`

to IE specific rules:

```
/*
 * The following two rules are for IE only and
 * should be wrapped in conditional comments.
 * The -ms-filter rule should be on one line 
 * and always *before* the filter rule if
 * used in the same rule.
 */

#transformedObject {

   /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=3.061515884555943e-16, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=3.061515884555943e-16, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

   /* IE6 and 7 */ 
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=3.061515884555943e-16,
            M12=1,
            M21=-1,
            M22=3.061515884555943e-16,
            SizingMethod='auto expand');


   /*
    * To make the transform-origin be the middle of
    * the object.    Note: These numbers
    * are approximations.  For more accurate results,
    * use Internet Explorer with this tool.
    */
   margin-left: 71px; 
   margin-top: -78px;

}
```