# textbox to rotate at an angle in asp.net?

Tags: html, textbox, rotation, angle, tilt

We have been trying to rotate a textbook at an angle(45,90,270 etc) on an aspx webform. I read that html won't support such a property, so we would have to include a CSS class property to the textbox. Is there a property to include an angle in a CSS class? We are using html 4.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS will allow you to rotate any element in modern browsers:

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

This is a fairly new feature, and a lot of browsers support it, but require a vendor prefix, so you should also specify `-moz-transform`, `-webkit-transform`, `-ms-transform`, so your full CSS will look like this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

This will support all browsers in common use except IE8 or earlier.

Old IE versions can rotate items, but it's much more difficult. You need to use the `filter` style, but it requires angles in radians and complex matrix formulae. There is an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie) that describes it in more detail.

However, you could use a javascript library called [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896). Then you can simply use this for old IE versions:

```
-sand-transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Add the above line to the CSS block I gave you earlier, and include the CSS Sandpaper javascript library in your HTML page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
-o-transform: rotate(30deg);
writing-mode: tb-rl;
```

for IE support to angle like 270 etc

```
  /* Internet Explorer */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

 -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
```

filter can accept one of four values: 0, 1, 2, or 3 which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees respectively

Comment: writing-mode: tb-rl; is the property which supports IE7+

Comment: Writing-mode will tilt it vertically. What about angles like 45 and 270?

Comment: IE is able to use `filter` to rotate by any angle, but it's much more complex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie for more info (or see my answer below for a nicer javascript-based alternative).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Indeed helpful and informative.