# how to put curved text by css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm building a webpage from PSD. At there, I've seen some little bit curved text.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Look the above 3 images. They aren't the straight line. They're little bit curved/oblique/awry. So, how can I make that text by CSS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a skew transformation would do the job: [CSS3 skew at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew)

Comment: *Note: The `skew()` function was present in early drafts. It has been removed but is still present in some implementations. Do not use it.*

Answer (score 0):

When you look closely, the baseline of the text is not curved but rotated. This transformation can be done with:

```
transform: rotate(5deg);
```

Be sure to support all browsers, e.g.:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 transforms. Make sure your target browsers support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d
Also, you might need to use prefixes to make it work in all browsers.

```
<p>Texty ipsum</p>

<style>
p {
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8 as stated on caniuse.com. To get it to work in IE8 you can look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie