# filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix does not work in IE8, 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, rotation, transform

I'm trying to rotate HTML element in IE8 and 7

according to this post

> [CSS rotate property in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)

this should work

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```

But it is not working. How can i fix this?

Comment: Where are you testing it ? If you are using IE dev tools, there is a problem with the transform filter. Try and test it with IETester.

Comment: Got it. It's because of the filter is disabled in IE10 dev tools. Thank you!