# CSS3 rotate in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried all possible options found here on stackoverflow to help IE8 to **transform: rotate**.
The only one which worked almost correctly is **cssSandpaper**. 
It rotates my navigation as needed, but when I test it in IETester it seems that *the real  links are positioned in inverse angle to horizon*, comparing to the navigation.

Here is a [print-screen](http://coderbit.net/ie8rotate.jpg)

I spent so much time now, searching for the reason this is heppenning.
Hope there are pros who can tell me whats the problem with it.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/3dyaY/)

code for nav is simple bootstrap:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
          <li><a class="lastNavLink" href="#">123</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

rotation in css

```
nav    {
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
      -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);  /* IE9 */
      transform: rotate(-4deg);  
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9975640502598243, M12=0.06975647374412515, M21=-0.06975647374412515, M22=0.9975640502598243, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
      zoom: 1;
    }
```

Javascripts all default in bootstrap + **cssSandpaper**.
Take a look at jsFiddle before code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Comment: Thank you @Thew, I read that, how does it solve my issue?

Comment: Your CSS doesn't seem to note anything cssSandpaper related (I.E `-sand-transform: rotate(40deg);`)

Comment: You are right, just tried it, doesn't change much.

Comment: Uhoh, I'll try some things.

Comment: @Thew, I would appreciate it a lot ))