# How to rotate <div> -45 degrees in IE7,8,9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How to rotate  -45 degree in IE7,8,9 ?

I can use on all browser beside IE , Thank for ans.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

i want to rotate with style

```
width: 200px;
height: 14px;
border: none;
background-image: url(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.png);
background-position-x: -46px;
background-position-y: 310px;
```

Comment: Look this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Comment: this question : CSS Rotate IE7 and 8 ---- rotate 90 degree