# How to show text when <div> rotate in ie?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How to show text when  rotate in ie ?

I success to rotate  in ie, but text in div not show , how can i do ?

```
<div style="
    width: 200px;
    height: 14px;
    border: none;
    background-image: url(http://image.ohozaa.com/i/47d/vliemC.png);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M22=0.7071067811865476, M21=-0.7071067811865475, M12=0.7071067811865475, M11=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M22=0.7071067811865476, M21=-0.7071067811865475, M12=0.7071067811865475, M11=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
">
Premium Seller.
</div>



<style type="text/css">
</style>
```

Comment: Which version of IE is causing the issue?

Comment: IE version? In 10 everything fine.

Comment: [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)