# rotate element using css in IE8 for -45deg

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I want to rotate an element in browsers including IE8. 
For all other browsers execpt IE8 I can do: `<vendor>-transform: rotate(-45deg)`

For IE8 I know I have to use `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix` but I'm unsure what matrix manipulations to set. My matrix brain is kind of rusty.

Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rotate property in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)

Comment: @Spudley: no. I asked specifically for tha matrix-manipulation for -45deg. That's not covered there.

Comment: Well, the answer you've accepted for 45deg is identical to the answer I gave there, so....? In any case, one of the other answers in that question links to a transform calculator that would also give the answer. And my suggestion use the CSS Sandpaper lib would allow you to use standard syntax with degrees rather than a matrix transform, which frankly is a much better idea anyway.

Comment: ahh my bad, didn't read the answers there, only the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
```

Comment: plugging in blindly for now, testing later. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this matrix generator to help : http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

this one is as well very helpfull : http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/