# How to put a border on a triangle shape using css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm working on a navigation bar with horizontal line with arrow and I want to put a border in the triangle like so: 
 
[image]

I want it to be like:

[image]

Here is the list:

```
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#foo" id="foo">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bar" id="bar">bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#baz" id="baz">baz</a></li>
   </ul>
```

And here's the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/1ho9utzs/)

**EDIT:** here's another 
[**source**](http://jhaurawachsman.com/2013/css-triangles-border-stroke), so how can I make it the other way around? I mean the triangle pointer in on the top?

Comment: What you tried?... you want us to code for you ....

Comment: @PhotographyBum I want to add a black border in the `triangle`. 
@kamesh Check the fiddle

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jhaurawachsman.com/2013/css-triangles-border-stroke/

Comment: you can generate triangle border from here: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: @azeós How can I make it `tri-up` for example?

Comment: you should take a look at here.. http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vuxuf/4/edit)**

[image: add arrow underneath selected list element]

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  background:#ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li a{
  color:#555;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
}
a.selected{
  color:#fff;
}
a.selected:after{                    /* Our arrow */
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  content:" ";
  width:8px;
  height:8px;
  border: 0 solid #555;
  border-width: 1px 0  0 1px;
  background:#fff;
  /* Now let's auto-center our arrow inside the pos. relative A parent */
  left:0;                           
  right:0;
  bottom:-5px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Using `:after` on your `a` element, just set two borders and the same background color (in order to cover the bottom border of the `ul`), than rotate your little square by 45° and you're done.

Comment: Neat, I think this is the best solution though OP is using safari .. you might need to add `-webkit-` prefix for transform.

Comment: I would like to point that IE8 & below don't support transform.

Comment: @ImranBughio For IE8 use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665189/rotate-element-using-css-in-ie8-for-45deg

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if I added `body { background:#1d428a; } for example  the color of `triangle` occupies it

Comment: @user3093453 as I said in my answer, use the same background color for the `:after` element (`#1d428a`)

Comment: @user3093453 otherwise wrap your navigation inside an `overflow:hidden` element and the arrow will not stick out of it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hi, what if I want to do this one on hover? how could I do that?

Comment: @user3093453 use the `:hover` pseudo.

Answer (score 1):

You can create css based triangle using **[THIS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)** code.

For what you need one way to do it is use 2 triangles one black and one white then move the white one a little below to show only 1px of black, creating an illusion of stroke :)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/1ho9utzs/3/)**

**Code:**

```
                a:target:before,
                a:target:after {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    left: 50%;
                    margin-left: -4px;
                    width: 0; 
                    height: 0; 
                    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
                    border-right: 8px solid transparent;

                    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
                }
                a:target:after{
                    bottom: -1px;
                    border-bottom-color: #fff;
                }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Please check my updated question I provided the source but I don't know on how to make the triangle to reverse

Comment: I think the link you just added is using the same trick as i am here ... did you check my fiddle isnt it what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I just check the the **[LINK](http://jhaurawachsman.com/2013/css-triangles-border-stroke/)** it's using the same technique as i am using here.

Comment: Yes but your `triangle` is not that straight I guess, I mean it's not pointed at all

Comment: what do you mean ? i have added a screenshot as well how is it not pointing ?

Comment: Oh I see it's not that good in `Safari`. And lastly why is it not centered?

Comment: hm you are right it renders badly in safari & Firefox for some reason - and yes i missed alignment.

Comment: I'm accepting Roco's answer, I'll give you upvote tho.

Comment: Yes i agree Roco's Method is smart & Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/1ho9utzs/)

```
a:target:before,
a:target:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    bottom: -1px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #fff;
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;

}

a:target:before {
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
a:target:after {
    border-bottom: 9px solid #000;
    border-width: 0 9px 9px 9px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
```

[image]