# CSS3 effect not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a pretty nice looking effect with some help from a website which works in every explorer expect for IE8-7 etc.. I researched and found that modernizer could help but didn't get it to work... here's the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.13486.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">.
<title>Amazing CSS3 Image Hover Over Boxes, Using Transitions.</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="square.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div id="center">

 <ul class="custom-menu"> 
<li>    
    <a href="#">
        <div class="content"> 
        <h2 class="link">Nivel Basico</h2>
        <h3 class="secondary">Aprenderás</h3> 
        <p class="info"><img src="images/Flaticon_43130(1).png"  /></p>
        <p class="icon" >Es capaz de comprender y utilizar expresiones cotidianas de uso muy frecuente, así como frases sencillas destinadas a satisfacer necesidades de tipo inmediato. Puede presentarse a si mismo y a otros, pedir  y dar información persona básica sobre su domicilio, sus pertenencias y las personas que conoce, Puede relacionarse de forma elemental siempre que su interlocutor hable despacio y con claridad y esté dispuesto a cooperar. </p>
        </div>
    </a> 
</li> 


  <li class="custom-menu1"> 
    <a href="#">
         <div class="content"> 
         <h2 class="link">Nivel Intermedio</h2>
         <h3 class="secondary">Aprenderás</h3> 
         <p class="info"><img src="images/Flaticon_43075.png" /></p>
<p class="icon"> Es capaz de comprender los puntos principales      de     textos  claros y en la lengua estándar si tratan sobre  cuestiones que le son   conocidas ya sea en situaciones de trabajo de estudio o de ocio, sabe desenvolverse en la mayor parte de las situaciones que pueden surgir durante un viaje por zonas donde se utiliza la lengua. Es capaz de producir textos sencillos y coherentes sobre temas que le son familiares o en lo que tiene un interés persona.</p>
        </div>
      </a> 
    </li> 



   <li class="custom-menu2">    
    <a href="#">
        <div class="content"> 
        <h2 class="link">Nivel Avanzado</h2>
        <h3 class="secondary">Aprenderás</h3>
        <p class="info"><img src="images/Flaticon_47028.png" /></p> 
        <p class="icon" > Es capaz de comprender con facilidad       prácticamente todo lo que oye o lee. Sabe reconstruir la información y los argumentos procedentes de diversas fuentes, ya sean en lengua hablada o escrita, y presentarlos de manera coherente y resumida.
Puede expresarse espontáneamente, con gran fluidez y con un grado de precisión que le permite diferenciar pequeños matices de significado incluso en situaciones de mayor complejidad.</p>          
        </div>
      </a> 
</li> 
 </ul> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and  here is the CSS

```
#center { 

   margin:  0px 0px 0px 0px;  

}


.custom-menu {
   margin:  0px 0px 0px 0px;  
   height: 400px; 
   width: 86%;
}   

.custom-menu ul {margin: 0 0 0 -4px;}

.custom-menu li { 
   width: 250px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   background: #fff;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
   border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;
   border-radius: 1px; 
   transition: 500ms; 
   -webkit-transition: 500ms; /* Safari & Chrome */
   -o-transition: 500ms; /* Opera */ 
   -moz-transition: 500ms; /* Old firefox */

 } 

.custom-menu li a { 
   text-align: center; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   border-style: none; 
} 


.custom-menu li:hover {
   border: 3px solid #29abe2;
   background-color: #014B67;
} 


 .content { 
    margin-top: 12px; 
 } 

 .link { 
    font-size: 23px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #29ABE2;   
    transition: 500ms; 
   -webkit-transition: 500ms;  /* Safari & Chrome */
   -o-transition: 500ms;   /* Opera */ 
   -moz-transition: 500ms;  /* Old firefox */
}

.custom-menu li:hover .link {
   color: #fff; 
   font-size: 18px; 
}

.secondary { 
   margin-top:-75px;
   color: #fff; 
   transition: 500ms;
   -webkit-transition: 500ms; /* Safari & Chrome */
   -o-transition: 500ms; /* Opera */ 
   -moz-transition: 500ms; /* Old firefox */
} 


.custom-menu li:hover .secondary { 
   background-color: #29abe2; 
   height: -70px; 
   padding-top: 4px; 
 } 

.info { 
   font-size: 18px; 
   color: #014B67;
   margin-top: 59px;  
   padding: 18px; 
   transition: 500ms;
   -webkit-transition: 500ms; /* Safari & Chrome */ 
   -o-transition: 500ms; /* Opera */ 
   -moz-transition: 500ms; /* Old Firefox */
} 

.custom-menu li:hover .info {
   transform: translateX(-400px) rotate(360deg); 
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px) rotate(360deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
   -o-transform: translateX(-400px) rotate(360deg);  /* Opera */
   -moz-transition: translateX(-400px) rotate(360deg);  /* Old Firefox */ 
}

.icon { 
   transition: 500ms; 
   -webkit-transition: 500ms; /* Safari & Chrome */  
   -o-transition: 500ms; /* Opera */ 
   -moz-transition: 500ms; /* Old Firefox */ 
   transform: translate(-300px) rotate(360deg);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-300px) rotate(360deg); /* Safari & Chrome */ 
   -o-transform: translate(-300px) rotate(360deg); /* Opera */ 
   -moz-transform: translate(-300px) rotate(360deg); /* Old Firefox */ 
} 

.custom-menu li:hover .icon { 
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Arial;
   color:white;
   text-align:justify;
   margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
   transform: translateY(-115px) rotate(0deg); 
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-115px) rotate(0deg); /* Safari & Chrome */ 
   -o-transform: translateY(-115px) rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
   -moz-transform: translateY(-206px) rotate(0deg); /* Old Firefox */ 
} 

/* Colors */ 
li.custom-menu1:hover { 
background-color: #009878;
}
li.custom-menu2:hover { 
background-color: #B0232A;
} 
li.custom-menu3:hover {

}
```

So.. it should work now on IE8, right? or am I missing something here?

Comment: modernizr can help, but it can't exactly make a horse & buggy suddenly be able to use a gas tank and feed the horses with it.

Comment: IE didn't support CSS transitions until IE10.

Comment: Is there any way I can get modernizr to work? I really have no clue in how to start.. or how can I make a effect only for EI8?' thank you Marc B, and Mike W, I didn't know that, thank you for your fast replay

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DXImageTransform.Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `rotate` or `translate` in `IE`

For **egs**,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

And

```
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); //for IE8
```

Look at [css-rotate-in-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie) for more information.