# Rotate IE7 90 degree

Tags: html, css, rotation, internet-explorer-7

Is there a way to rotate IE7 90% (the whole page)? I tried to rotate body and HTML element 90 degree by using CSS, but scroll bars are displaying because the width and height are not fix the window. I just want to rotate whole html 90% and the width and height are fix the window. Please help me.

How can I do that? (Maybe using CSS or something else). Thank so much.

Sorry about my English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rotate property in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following links which may help you:

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

or perhaps:

http://raphaeljs.com/

Raphael supports rotation for IE6 onwards, I hope this helps you in your research.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code that will support in all browser,

```
/*rotate 60 degrees*/
#rotate60 {
  /*General*/
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  /*Firefox*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  /*Microsoft Internet Explorer*/
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  /*Chrome, Safari*/
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  /*Opera*/
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
  /*alter opacity*/
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
/*rotate 90 degrees*/
#rotate90 {
  /*General*/
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*Firefox*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*Microsoft Internet Explorer*/
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*Chrome, Safari*/
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*Opera*/
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*alter opacity*/
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

and use overflow hidden for scrolling part.

Comment: -1 this won't work for <= IE8. Also, what does `opacity` has to do with `rotating`?