# css transform rotate not working in ie8 even after implementing filter

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I want to implement `transform:rotate(310deg)` but it didnt work in **IE8**.I recently read that filter will work in **IE8** but this code is not properly running in **IE8**.Please suggest a proper polyfill for css.

```
.ai:after{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:inherit;margin-left:9px;color:#000000;color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=-0.70710678, M21=0.70710678, M22=0.70710678,sizingMethod='auto expand');
        -moz-transform:  matrix(0.70710678, 0.70710678, -0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform:  matrix(0.70710678, 0.70710678, -0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0, 0);
        -o-transform:  matrix(0.70710678, 0.70710678, -0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0, 0);
    transform:  matrix(0.70710678, 0.70710678, -0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: transparent #fff #fff transparent;content:"";height:8px;right:1px;top:-3px;width:8px;display:inline-block;margin-top:-8px;position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate by 45 degrees in IE, you need the following code in your stylesheet:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```

See here for more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617511/2161568