# Can I draw a line from one element to another in css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

My site consists of three columns of elements, which can be scrolled up and down. The user selects one in each column, and the elements in each of the columns are joined by lines. However, my issue is: how can I track the absolute position of the element on the page to draw the endpoints of the array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270485/drawing-lines-on-html-page

Comment: There is get offset in jquery that return offset position of element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
var left = $('css-selector').offset().left;
var top = $('css-selector').offset().top;
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`jQuery.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/): Get the current coordinates [...] relative to the document.