# Connecting nodes with lines using Javascript/JQuery and HTML (no canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry

I'm close, but my math is all kinds of screwed up somewhere or something...

[Here is a fiddle of the current state.](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/RHX75/1/)

**Here are the nodes and lines:**

```
drawnode(entity, 200, 200);
drawnode(entity, 200, 300);
drawnode(entity, 400, 300);

drawline(200, 200, 200, 300);
drawline(200, 300, 400, 300);
drawline(400, 300, 200, 200);
```

**Here is the result:**

[image: I put the TRY in geometry]

**Here are my two functions**:

```
function drawnode(x, y) {

    var ele = ""
    var style = "";
    style += "position:absolute;";
    style += "z-index:100;"
    ele += "<div class='relNode' style="+ style + ">";
    ele += "<span> Test Node</span>"
    ele += "<div>"

    $('#rPaper').show();
    var node = $(ele).appendTo('#rPaper');
    var width = node.width();
    var height = node.height();

    var centerX = width / 2;
    var centerY = height / 2;

    var startX = x - centerX;
    var startY = y - centerY;

    node.css("left", startX).css("top", startY);

}

function drawline(ax, ay, bx, by) {
    if (ay > by) {
        bx = ax + bx;
        ax = bx - ax;
        bx = bx - ax;
        by = ay + by;
        ay = by - ay;
        by = by - ay;
    }
    var calc = Math.atan((ay - by) / (bx - ax));
    calc = calc * 180 / Math.PI;
    var length = Math.sqrt((ax - bx) * (ax - bx) + (ay - by) * (ay - by));
    var style = ""
    style += "height:" + length + "px;"
    style += "width:1px;"
    style += "background-color:black;"
    style += "position:absolute;"
    style += "top:" + (ay) + "px;"
    style += "left:" + (ax) + "px;"
    style += "transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);"
    style += "-ms-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);"
    style += "transform-origin:0% 0%;"
    style += "-moz-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);"
    style += "-moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;"
    style += "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);"
    style += "-webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;"
    style += "-o-transform:rotate(" + calc + "deg);"
    style += "-o-transform-origin:0% 0%;"
    style += "-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);"
    style += "box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);"
    style += "z-index:99;"
    $("<div style='" + style + "'></div>").appendTo('#rPaper');
}
```

I'm sure it's something terribly stupid.

Credit for drawline function goes to [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14560350/736893), though I've modified it and somehow broken it.

edit: I don't believe my question is a duplicate of [the suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs). That is very generic while mine is specific with semi-functional code and a defined logical problem which has already been solved.  The accepted answer there uses a 3rd party library, which was not an option for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two draggable divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-draggable-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBmvK/) with testcases.

I changed 3 things:

1. `calc` changed to `angle` and additional change:

   angle = -angle;
2. exchange `width` and `height`. Rectange is defined with x,y,widht,height. I am more used to that arrangment.
3. Added check `if (ax > bx) {` instead of `if (ay > by) {`

Problem is actually how to draw narrow horizontal rectangle (line) and then rotate it correctly.