# How to draw a line linking two elements on HTML page?

Tags: html

I want to draw a line on HTML web page dynamically to connect two html elements, which can move on html page. 
This action is something like connect two Rectangle's angle, like this:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Need more details, what do you mean by 'connect 2 html elements'? Generally you use canvas for Drawing purposes.

Comment: If you'd rather use CSS than HTML5 canvas, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4270485/21727) is your duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this tutorial. This tutorial teach you how to draw lines by HTML Canvas API.

**HTML5 Canvas Line Tutorial**

> To draw a line using HTML5 Canvas, we can use the beginPath(),
>   moveTo(), lineTo(), and stroke() methods.
>
> First, we can use the beginPath() method to declare that we are about
>   to draw a new path.  Next, we can use the moveTo() method to position
>   the context point (i.e. drawing cursor), and then use the lineTo()
>   method to draw a straight line from the starting position to a new
>   position.  Finally, to make the line visible, we can apply a stroke to
>   the line using stroke().  Unless otherwise specified, the stroke color
>   is defaulted to black.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

Comment: Please post the relevant excerpt from the linked website in case the link goes dead.

Comment: I added the excerpt from the linked webbsite.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. Thanks for improving your answer!

Answer (score -3):

You could use the HTML5 canvas but you will have to be more specific with your question so we can help you further.